# Magento exception.log PDOException cause and fix?

Tags: magento

Working for a small company running a Magento-based (1.7.0.2 version) webstore, and for a while we've had the following error pop up in the exception.log:

```
2013-03-04T10:17:24+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1' in *website root*/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 *website root*/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 *website root*/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 *website root*/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 *website root*/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 *website root*/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#5 *website root*/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#6 *website root*/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#8 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Model_Rewrite_CatalogCategory), Object(Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Model_Rewrite_CatalogCategory), NULL)
#9 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Model_Rewrite_CatalogCategory))
#10 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(141): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
#11*website root*/var/ait_rewrite/6bfe16ca572eea47db567910902c6209.php(864): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#12 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(191): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#14 *website root*/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(134): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#15 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(502): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<h2><a href="ht...')
#16 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php(54): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<h2><a href="ht...')
#17 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/6bfe16ca572eea47db567910902c6209.php(865): Mage_Cms_Block_Block->_toHtml()
#18 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/6bfe16ca572eea47db567910902c6209.php(865): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#20 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/6bfe16ca572eea47db567910902c6209.php(584): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/6bfe16ca572eea47db567910902c6209.php(528): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#22 *website root*/app/design/frontend/default/*store view*/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(70): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#23 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/67b58abff9e6bd7b400bb2fc1903bf2f.php(412): include('*website root*...')
#24 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/67b58abff9e6bd7b400bb2fc1903bf2f.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#25 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/67b58abff9e6bd7b400bb2fc1903bf2f.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#26 *website root*/var/ait_rewrite/6bfe16ca572eea47db567910902c6209.php(865): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#29 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(147): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#30 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(14722, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#31 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#32 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#33 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 *website root*/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 *website root*/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 *website root*/index.php(85): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

We have been searching for similar problems, but can't find any solved questions matching this, we are not even sure what's causing it, any help will be appreciated. If you need more information, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue due to conflicts with "AITOC" module which is rewriting most of the common magento blocks. Just check with them they will help you further. Its nothing because of Magento. Its mostly related with AITOC licensing based on your domains.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, we are now in contact with AITOC. Will respond further if anything is or isn't found.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to reproduce the error? Their support is asking for it and I can't find how the error comes to be.

Comment: @LuckyNobody Do you mean you don't have that error now ? I came across the same kind of error because of AITOC module rewriting the core blocks for caching. And eventually we figured out its because of the module license issue for the test domain name that we used. Earlier we were using a test store domain name which doesn't match their conditions. Finally we identified thats the root cause and they just re-installed the module and fixed it seamlessly.

Comment: The error keeps coming on the exception.log, but we can't find a way to reproduce it manually. It just seems to pop up randomly and I've been going through the website just trying to make that error come up. The reason I'm asking is because their support is asking how to reproduce the error before they start checking the place out.

Comment: @LuckyNobody No very sure. It seems the AITOC folders / Blocks don't have right permission.... In the error message you have listed above its product listing block.... So try to change the permissions of the AITOC module folders and block files to reproduce the error and but make sure to note down what you are doing.